# Android: How to check the TextView value that get from MySQL with string "pending"?

Tags: java, mysql

Currently, my EditText will display any value that store in a column named 'comment'. But, if the EditText display text "pending" which is retrieved from that column(comment), it should not display automatically. I want to know, how to avoid the EditText from displaying "pending"?. Should be used if else statement? But how?

Below is the EditText code that displays a text which is retrieved from MySQL.

```
etComment.setText(user.getComment());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **If-Else** condition to avoid display the "pending" in the edit text.

**Code:**

```
if(!user.getComment().equals("Pending")){
        etComment.setText(user.getComment());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mate !! How can I forgot "!" during testing :D